# Conversion of C# decimal values of System.Array in into string

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a very strange problem in C# application. The problem is consistent, but only on one remote computer. The `data` below contains decimal numbers. I perform the following simplified operation:

```
Array data = (Array)get_data(); // array of decimals
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(data.GetValue(0));
string s = sb.ToString();
```

This converts numbers like 14.62 into "14,62", i.e comma instead of dot. Later, when I parse this string into `double`, it generates errors. How to prevent this?

Please note, that I don't have access to that remote computer. I can only adjust the program's code, and then send a new installer.

Comment: That's a cultural formatting issue, based on the workstation OS settings.  You could force the formatting in ToString(), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(((double)data.GetValue(0)).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why the invariant culture? If this value is displayed, wouldn't it make more sense to pass `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Ahh I was assuming the `ToString` and `Parse` were happening in the same locale, which of course wouldn't be a problem. If this value is changing locale's, then that would explain it.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the different output because of the remote computer's culture. Some culture uses `,` as decimal separators and some uses `.`. To override that you have to call `ToString` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. You can also use the following one liner which would give you the same thing.

```
string s = string.Join(",", 
                        data.OfType<decimal>()
                        .Select(r=> r.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

*(I assumed that you needed a delimiter separated string for your data elements, since you were using StringBuilder)*

Comment: Yes, you assumed correctly, and it's great to know how to convert the whole array. But in my case it's a 2-dimensional array where the first column is decimal and the second - integers. (this is how it comes from an external API). Anyway, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue I cloned the Culture Invariant( makes it en-US)

```
    private string ConvertPriceFormat(double amount)
{
    string price = string.Empty;

    // NumberFormatInfo of InvariantCulture thousandseparator = "," DecimalSeparator="."
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();

    // make Changes for the Injection
    nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "";

    // Format the price with the defined format
    price = amount.ToString("n", nfi);

    return price;
}
```

Just need to change it to go from string to double